# Finding the angle for a series of points

Tags: trigonometry

I have a series of points such that:

```
R1 = D1 * cos(C + A1)
R2 = D2 * cos(C + A2)
etc
```

R should be the same each time (with some small variation). I want to solve these for C, so:

```
D1 * cos(C + A1) = D2 * cos(C + A2)
```

Someone pointed out that:

```
cos(a + b) = cos(a) * cos(b) - sin(a) * sin(b)
```

So:

```
D1 * (cos(C) * cos(A1) - sin(C) * sin(A1)) = D2 * (cos(C) * cos(A2) - sin(C) * sin(A2))
```

But now I'm stuck. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: But are $R_1$ and $R_2$ equal?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Poorly explained.

Comment: Do you want to take into account the variations of the $R_i$ or are are they strictly constant ?

Comment: The use case here is actually observing a car driving down a road. R is the distance from the observer to the car at it's closest point so should be relatively constant. However, there are cases like two lanes or a curved road that I haven't considered yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D_1, D_2, A_1, A_2$ are given, then

$$\begin{align*}
D_1 \cos (C+A_1) &= D_2 \cos (C+A_2)\\
D_1(\cos C \cos A_1 - \sin C\sin A_1)&= D_2(\cos C \cos A_2 - \sin C\sin A_2)\\
D_1 \cos C \cos A_1 - D_1 \sin C\sin A_1 &= D_2 \cos C\cos A_2 - D_2\sin C\sin A_2\\
D_2 \sin C \sin A_2 - D_1 \sin C \sin A_1 &= D_2 \cos C \cos A_2 - D_1 \cos C \cos A_1\\
\sin C(D_2 \sin A_2 - D_1 \sin A_1) &= \cos C(D_2 \cos A_2 - D_1 \cos A_1)\\
\frac{\sin C}{\cos C}
&= \frac{D_2\cos A_2 - D_1\cos A_1}{D_2\sin A_2 - D_1\sin A_1}\\
\tan C 
&= \frac{D_2\cos A_2 - D_1\cos A_1}{D_2\sin A_2 - D_1\sin A_1}\\
\end{align*}$$

This gives two possible $C$ within each $2\pi$ range, the two possible values differ by $\pi$. The two possible values of $C$ give different $R$ with opposite signs:

$$R = D_i\cos(C + A_i) \implies D_i \cos [(\pi + C) + A_i] = -R$$

So if the sign of $R$ is known, it's important to choose the correct $C$ that gives the right sign of $R$.